# Как задать адаптивный размер шрифта, чтобы он корректно отображался и на больших и на малых экранах?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как задать адаптивный размер шрифта, чтобы он корректно отображался и на больших и на малых экранах?Пробовал в единицах vw, но при использовании такого размера шрифт некорректно масштабируется, слишком сильно уменьшается при уменьшении экрана. Em, rm и % также плохо масштабируются. Может, есть какие-то дополнительные настройки, например с помощью jquery?

```
<p class="heading" style="font-size:2vw;">Привет</p>
```

Comment: Я на одном из сайтов почти не задавал размеры шрифтов - использовал размер по умолчанию, плюс тегами типа h1 small. Немного дробных значений типа 0.9ем, для не основных э

Comment: не основных элементов. Прекрасно масштабируется. Медиа запросами для мелких/крупных экранов задал размеры всплывающих окон (DHTML).

Comment: обычные медиа запросы и ни какого js

Comment: Для каждого media-запроса отдельный font-size назначать? Это практикуется повсеместно?

Comment: @ArturHan да там собственно медиа запросов то будет не много ...3 или 4 да и предел размера шрифта 14 пикселей если не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй такое:

`font-size: calc(Xpx + Yvw)`

Коэффициент X будет выступать в качестве некого фиксированного ограничителя минимального размера шрифта, Y будет выступать как коэффициент скейлинга размера шрифта от размеров области видимости